# How to work with vertices of object loaded by ObjLoader in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, objloader

I have a object loaded in my scene by ObjLoader. But then i need to read that object vertices. But i still cant find out how to do it. On normal cube what i made in three.js I can read and change vertices without problem but on object loaded by ObjLoader it do not work. I also tried to use FaceNormalsHelper which also works on cube but dont on my object.

Here is my code:

```
    //My cube this works
    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(20, 20, 20);
    var color = new THREE.Color("rgba(188, 141, 190, 1)");
    var material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial({color: color.getHex()});
    var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

    var helpeer = new THREE.FaceNormalsHelper( cube, 20, 0x00ff00, 1 );
    var vert = cube.geometry.vertices[1].y;

    scene.add( cube );
    scene.add( helpeer );

    //Loading my object 
    var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
    manager.onProgress = function ( item, loaded, total ) {
        console.log( item, loaded, total );
    };
    var texture = new THREE.Texture();
    var onProgress = function ( xhr ) {
        if ( xhr.lengthComputable ) {
            var percentComplete = xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100;
            console.log( Math.round(percentComplete, 2) + '% downloaded' );
        }
    };
    var onError = function ( xhr ) {
    };
    var loader = new THREE.ImageLoader( manager );
    loader.load( 'objects/textura.jpg', function ( image ) {
        texture.image = image;
        texture.needsUpdate = true;
    } );

    var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader( manager );
    loader.load( 'objects/scan_leg_repair.obj', function ( object ) {
        object.traverse( function ( child ) {
            if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
                child.material.map = texture;
            }
        } );

        object.position.y = - 100;
        object.rotation.x = -1.5;
        object.rotation.z = 3;

        scene.add( object );

        //That is what i tried. Without success :(
        //var vert2 = object.geometry.vertices[1].y;
        //var vert3 = object.children[0].geometry.vertices[1].y;
        //var helper = new THREE.FaceNormalsHelper( object, 20, 0x00ff00, 1 );
        //var helper = new THREE.FaceNormalsHelper( object.children[0], 20, 0x00ff00, 1 );
        //scene.add( helper );

    }, onProgress, onError );
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: The type of geometry is `THREE.BufferGeometry()`, thus its vertices are in a buffer attribute, eg `object.geometry.attributes.position`.

Comment: I have same problem. I tried this var vrt = object.geometry.attributes.position;
                                                                console.log(vrt); but get error Cannot read property 'attributes' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

OBJLoader create object as `THREE.group`.
So you can access vertices below way.

```
object.children[0].geometry.attributes.position
```